# In Huffman code compression determining code table bits

Tags: huffman-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWY7p.png)

In the above picture, as you can see in first paragraph 11th senetence, 
"For our example the code table may saved in 5*8+4*2=48"
How this expression come out? Please explain...

Comment: read it again. four 8bit chars + one 8bit terminator + four 2bit chars.

Comment: Oh then in 5*8, 5 is composed with 4 bits for char and one bits for terminator? Then What is the terminator?

Answer (score 0):

It says:

> number of table entries, code 1, symbol 1, code 2, symbol 2, ...

So that's what it is. One byte for the number of table entries, which in this case is 4. From that, you can determine that the number of bits in each code is 2. That is followed by two bits for the first code (00), followed by eight bits for the first symbol ("a").

That header is then followed by the coded data, two-bits per symbol.

There is a flaw though in this encoding scheme, assuming that you get a file that is a sequence of bytes. There is no way to know how many symbols there are in the last byte, which could be 1, 2, 3, or 4. You would also need another two bits in the header to tell you how many symbols are in the last byte.

Comment: This could also be solved by having an explicit EOF symbol, no?

Comment: Yes, but that would be more expensive unless the message was very short. One of the symbols would need to be one bit longer so the code lengths would be 2,2,2,3,3 instead of 2,2,2,2. That would proportionally increase the size of the entire message, instead of just add a few bits. The few bits at the beginning takes advantage of the additional information stored in the file directory about the length of the file, requiring only a few more bits to indicate how many bits in the last byte are used.